# How can I effectively create a full face mask?

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing, units

So I am having some problems, especially with stupid covid messing up my search. I am trying to create a full face mask in Blender but can't as I there seems to be no way to set the circumference of an object like a cylinder and when I tried searching online for measurements to help it just showed me useless results of masks to help protect against covid, and I don't want that mask, even including full face mask does nothing.

So does anyone know any effective way to create a full face mask in Blender, an example would be a mask like a hacker's mask or the mask Jason Voorhees wears, the hockey mask. I got results from the hockey mask, such as the circumference but I can't see to find a way to set the circumference of an object in Blender.

Any help is appreciated, as the internet is no help. I mean, I pretty much need to learn how to set the circumference of an object, such as a cylinder and I am good, but if you got any other ideas, please share. I could also just manually set it with each ring, but that would literally take forever and to get it right, it will keep changing, then I would have to quickly reset it, and it will take forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to make a face mask is to start with a face and then edit it.  But it sounds like your question here is less how to make a face mask than how to create a cylinder with a specific circumference.

Blender doesn't create cylinders on the basis of circumference, but it does create cylinders on the basis of radius, and the two are proportional-- circumference is equal to radius * 2 * pi, so radius is equal to circumference / (2 * pi).  If you want to create a cylinder with a specific circumference:

1. Create a cylinder.
2. Look at the operator panel (F6 for me, but our initial interface choices may have differed.)
3. In the radius field of the operator panel, type "c/(2*pi)", where "c" is the circumference you want.

Most fields in Blender allow entering simple math like this directly.

Comment: Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I actually never knew you could add in math equations to the fields, that is amazing.